# How to deploy ASP.NET 5 app to Azure without triggering build in Azure with VS code

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, visual-studio-code, azure-deployment, dnu

What is the best way to deploy the output of `dnu publish` to Azure website? I do not want build to trigger at the Azure side, because it takes forever and often breaks.

Answer (score 1):

One trick i do is to exclude un needed folders such as bower or node packages or any other folders by adding it to the exclude configuration in project.json.

check out a reference for the project.json exclude list to follow: http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/projects.html#building

hope this helps.